# C# TCP client read occasionally receives no data - 'nothing'

Tags: c#, string, tcpclient, tcp

I have written a TCP client which communicates with a server. In a dedicated 'listening' thread, I have the code as below. It should only read data when there is some data there. (`if (stream.DataAvailable)`)

Oddly, occasionally my program will crash because the stream will read absolutely no data. It will return an empty `string`. Even more oddly, if I try and 'catch' an empty string in the `handleResponse(string s)` function, it doesn't get caught.

```
    public void listenForResponses()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Listening...");
        while (isConnected == true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep (updateRate);
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            if (stream.DataAvailable) {
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read (data, 0, data.Length);
                Console.WriteLine (" >> Data size = "+data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (data, 0, bytes);
                output = responseData+"";
                handleResponse (output);
            }
            if (isConnected == false) {
                closeConnection ();
            }
        }
    }

public void handleResponse(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Received: "+msg); 
    iterateThroughEachCharInString (msg);
    if ((msg != "")&&(msg != null)&&(msg != " ")) {
        JSONDataObject desrlzdResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONDataObject>(msg);

        if ((desrlzdResp.instruction != null)) {
            if (desrlzdResp.instruction == "TestConn") {
                handleTestConn (desrlzdResp);
            } else if (desrlzdResp.instruction == "SceneOver") {
                handleSceneFinished (desrlzdResp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is `System.NullReferenceException` on the line `if ((desrlzdResp.instruction != null))` of the `handleResponse` function

Comment: You're assuming one Send() corresponds to one Receive(), but that's not how sockets work. `responseData` can contain one message, multiple, or partial messages. You need a framing protocol to distinguish these situations, for example by prefixing your data with a number indicating how many bytes will follow. Try seaching.

Comment: Well,it seems that `desrlzdResp` is null, so adding a `if (desrlzdResp != null)..` after`JSONDataObject desrlzdResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONDataObject>(msg);` should avoid the nullreference exception

Comment: @Pikoh no, then you'll lose data. The `handleResponse()` can receive partial or multiple messages, causing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to fail. OP needs to ensure they call `handleResponse()` only with complete messages.

Comment: @CodeCaster of course you are absolutely right, and your first comment is the way to go. My comment is just in order to avoid the NullReference Exception, obviously is not a solution to the logic behind :)

Comment: your json deserialization is not working correctly. without seeing your data it is tricky to comment further. I think the framing protocol is handled by the first few bytes of the message containing a length - though a less rudimentary framing mechanism is probably indicated. You also need to cater for frames with less than the full message.

Comment: Is that closeconnection safe btw? Seems to me there's a chance that isConnected gets set to false after the if(isConnected) clause. And there is no close connection after the while loop. Off topic though

Comment: @CodeCaster You mean like this, right? http://pastebin.com/Mq84nj7S

Comment: @Ben no, that just reads until there's no more data. You can do something like `socket.WriteInt32(message.Length); socket.WriteBytes(message);`. Then the receiver can do `int messageLength = socket.ReadInt32(); while (bytesReceived < messageLength) { ... }`.

Comment: @Pikoh very sensible, I have changed it to read `JSONDataObject desrlzdResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONDataObject>(msg);
if ((desrlzdResp != null)&&(desrlzdResp.instruction != null))`

Comment: @Ben no, Pikoh's solution is not very sensible, it introduces a bug. In the situation that you receive one or more partial messages (such as `[messa` or `ge][mess`), your code will ignore that data.

Comment: So @CodeCaster, your solution is essentially: Create a protocol whereby the sender first sends the recipient a fixed length message containing the length of the data which the recipient should read in the subsequent read. Then, the recipient knows exactly how much to read, so should proceed to read from the stream. If the length is 0, don't read anything. Have I got that right?

Comment: Yes, see also the answer you received.

Comment: @CodeCaster Why would it be a bad idea to do what I'm currently doing (pastebin.com/Mq84nj7S ), and if *(as above)* `desrlzdResp` is null, empty, etc, do nothing?

Comment: Because that code is assuming way too much. `readLength` and `stream.DataAvailable` will not help you.

Comment: @CodeCaster i don't think my comment (is not a solution, just a comment to deal with an exception) introduces any bug. As you stated, OP needs to ensure they call handleResponse() only with complete messages, so if partial messages are passed to that method, the loose of data is not the extra check added's fault. :)

Comment: @Pikoh the null check hides the actual problem, and OP was going to use it as a solution. Your comment did not explicitly mention that is was not a full solution.

Comment: Pikoh and CodeCaster Thank you for both of your comments, and @Baaleos for your answer - much appreciated :)

Comment: @CodeCaster ok. I don't agreee,but let's keep it that way ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network Streams have a habit of advertising data available even when they are not active. Furthermore, there is no way for the receiver to know how long the incoming stream is unless the sender advertises it before hand.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Method designed to allow the sending of Byte[] data to the Peer
        /// Because this is using NetworkStreams - the first 4 bytes sent is the data length
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="TheMessage"></param>
        public void SendBytesToPeer(byte[] TheMessage)
        {

            try
            {
                long len = TheMessage.Length;

                byte[] Bytelen = BitConverter.GetBytes(len);

                PeerStream.Write(Bytelen, 0, Bytelen.Length);
                PeerStream.Flush();
                PeerStream.Write(TheMessage, 0, TheMessage.Length);
                PeerStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Note - the flushing on the sender side might not be needed, but I add it in as it does no harm - Microsoft says that flush does nothing to network streams.

So this code will determine the size of the message you are sending, and then send that to the receiver ahead of your 'actual' message.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Incoming bytes are retrieved in this method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disconnected"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private byte[] ReceivedBytes(ref bool disconnected)
        {
            try
            {
                //byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int receivedDataLength = 0;
                byte[] data = { };
                int len = 0;
                int i = 0;
                PeerStream.ReadTimeout = 15000;


                if (PeerStream.CanRead)
                {
                    //networkStream.Read(byteLen, 0, 8)
                    byte[] byteLen = new byte[8];
                    if (_client.Client.IsConnected() == false)
                    {
                        //Fire Disconnect event
                        if (OnDisconnect != null)
                        {
                            disconnected = true;
                            OnDisconnect(this);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    while (len == 0)
                    {
                        PeerStream.Read(byteLen, 0, 8);

                        len = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteLen, 0);
                    }
                    data = new byte[len];

                    PeerStream.Read(data, receivedDataLength, len);

                    return data;
                }



            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {

                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exception:" + E.ToString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This code will wait until the receiver has detected an incoming stream length, then it will attempt to read that exact length.
Don't worry about the OnDisconnect bit- that's just some code I left in from a project I was doing. You may want to consider adding a Thread.Sleep within the while(len == 0) loop, to save your CPU Cycles.